# Daily write requests per project - Cloud function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a project in which I have created a **HTTP cloud function**. Now attendance machines sends data to a windows software which in turn calls my HTTP API to insert data into Firestore. I just learned that I have a limit of 50 writes per minute.

> The number of daily write requests per project (50 default)

My **Google Cloud function** writes in db like this -

```
firestore.collection("attendance").doc(uniqueId).collection("inout").add(body).then((resp: any) => {
    response.send({ status: 'OK', message: 'data save successfully' });
```

Note: I am on blaze [pay-as-you-go] plan.

Now I wanted to know, I can at max insert 50 records in Firestore per minute as per `WriteRequestsPerMinutePerProject`? If yes then how can it be increased ?

Comment: Where did you read this? Can you share any links ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I at max insert 50 records in firestore per minute as per WriteRequestsPerMinutePerProject ??

No, you can insert thousands of documents *per minute.* You can check all [usage and limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas) in the documentation.

Comment: Please have a look at this - https://ibb.co/Yd7Q0pw , what is this 50 limit ? May be I am being mistaken, please guide.

Comment: API calls (WRITE) - Calls to deploy or delete functions via the Cloud Functions API - 80 per 100 seconds , per project...what is this ?

Comment: @user2828442 "Calls to deploy or delete functions" clearly says deploying functions. When you run `firebase deploy` command, it uses that API and you don't deploy so frequently.